# How to check if the grammar or syntax of a sentence is correct or not (simple grammar check in Swift)?

Tags: swift, nlp, automated-tests

Hi I am working on testing a mobile app that can generate a description about objects or scenes. Is there a way to check if the sentence generated by the app has the correct grammar/syntax? I am using Swift.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in support for checking the grammar of a sentence in Swift, nor am I aware of anything like that built into iOS. English grammar is quite complex, and then there's the issue of supporting multiple languages. It's a non-trivial problem.

You might be able to find a third party grammar checking library. I suggest googling "iOS grammar checking framework" or similar.

Comment: Are you sure? What about  UITextChecker  ? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextchecker

Comment: @LeoDabus, UITextChecker is a spell checker, which is a simpler problem.

Comment: IMO it is probably what OP is looking for

Comment: The OP asked about checking grammar or syntax. That is a different problem than checking spelling. I assume that if they wanted to check spelling, they would have asked about *that* instead.

Comment: NSSpellChecker can do it, but that's macOS only